# Can anybody recommend an open source VPN for Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: firefox, vpn

All the ones I have seen either aren't open source OR don't work on Linux without a lot of progamming int he terminal, which frankly is beyong me.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not open source but I have to recommend [Private Internet Access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) as a customer.  They are one of the oldest, cheapest, and most reputable VPN providers.

As far as open source, OpenVPN is the gold standard but does require some configuration but there is plenty of documentation.